# How to title specific number of columns in Latex table?

Tags: latex

I have this table in Latex, I want to make the "Volume" heading only above columns 2-4, is this possible?

````
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{Volume ($m^{3}$)} \\
 \hline
 Waste Category& Reported 1 April 2019 &Estimated Future Arisings &Lifetime Total\\
 \hline
 HLW   & AF    &AFG&   004\\
 ILW&   AX  & ALA   &248\\
 LLW&AL & ALB&  008\\
 VLLW    &DZ & DZA&  012\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJycu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYzrh.png
````

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of this code fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a small adjustment to the multicolumn row:

```
& \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{Volume ($m^{3}$)} \\
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: the first `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` is rather unnecessary and can cause alignment problems depending on the column type (which the OP unfortunately did not tell us)

Comment: I tried this, but it has had a strange effect: It does not only place the heading above the final 3 columns

Comment: I will attach a photo of what that does, thank you for your help though, we are closer!

Comment: It seems that you've written `\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{Volume ($m^{3}$)} &` instead of `& \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{Volume ($m^{3}$)}`.

Comment: @sw14928 It would be much easier to help you if you would make a [mre] that would allow us to reproduce your problem

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz how can I do this? I tried, but it did not work

Comment: @sw14928 Make a small compilable test document that contains all the code necessary to reproduce your problem, and then add this to your question. This way people willing to help you don't have to type all the boring stuff like `\documentclass` etc.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ah I see this makes sense, so sorry about that, but thank you for your advice!